# Error with rdrop2 redirect uri

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, rstudio, dropbox

I'm kind of ignorant how API apps work.

My objective is to be able too use `rdrop2` package in R to get some files from my local machine from my own dropbox account. I already create an APP within my dropbox account.

But i don't understand what redirect uri should i configure, nor understand how the concept applies in this case.

The reason i bring this app is because i keep getting this error when trying to identify myself:

```
drop_auth(new_user = FALSE
      , key = app_key
      , secret = app_secret
      , cache = TRUE)
```

Im redirected to the browser, but i get en error 404 with the message:

```
Invalid `redirect_uri`. It must exactly match one of the redirect URIs you've pre-configured for your app (including the path).
```

What should I configure? and how? are there any other considerations i should have? and if possible, could someone explain whats happening?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pre-register a "redirect URI" for your app. This is the URL on your app where the user should be sent back to after they authorize your app to connect to their Dropbox account. You can pre-register it on the app's page on the [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) under the "OAuth 2" section.

You can find more information on this in [the Dropbox OAuth 2 documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize). The [OAuth Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide) may also be helpful.